# AngularJS routeprovider injection error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS, and I'm now trying the `$routeProvider`, but I can't get it to work.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`view.html`:

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

`controllers.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/something",{
            templateUrl: "view.html",
            controller: "MyController"
        })
        .otherwhise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
    }
);

function MyController($scope){

}
```

Whenever I run this, I get an error message that says

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `app.config(['$routeProvider'],
    function($routeProvider){`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `.otherwhise` to `.otherwise`.

A good practice when you run into these issues is to try the un-minified version of Angular.

The un-minified error is much more helpful:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App
>   due to: TypeError: Object # has no method 'otherwhise'

Comment: Stupid of me! Thanks for the tip on the non-minified version, the errors of the minified version are extremely cryptic.

Comment: "A good practice when you run into these issues is to try the un-minified version of Angular. The un-minified error is much more helpful:" - that helped me resolve mine. (y)

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Create a $inject property on your route config as follows: -

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);

(function (app) {
    var routeConfig = function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/something",{
            templateUrl: "view.html",
            controller: "MyController"
        })
        .otherwhise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
    };
    routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
    app.config(routeConfig);
})(angular.module("App"));
```

AngularJS will now be able to inject $routeProvider successfully when js is minified.